# Why do words like thence fall out of use?

Tags: language-change

It happens sometimes that rather useful words disappear.  A word like
*thence,* for example, is very useful, and has to be replaced if it is
taken out of the language by something less concise (and less elegant),
namely *from there.* It's rather mysterious to me that this should
happen.  Why do such words ever fall out of use?

Comment: Because language is not (most of the time) something that people deliberately shape: not for concision, or for any other purpose. It is something that most people use without introspection, and may not even be aware whether they are adopting novel forms of expression (and hence, often, dropping existing forms). [Notice that I used _hence_, quite naturally!]

Comment: If you look at [the paradigm that _thence_ fits into](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf), you see that it's in ruins in Modern English, with some words still in use, but plenty more unable to find a nesting place now that the categories aren't clear and inflection is dying.

Answer (score 4):

As @jlawler pointed out in the comments, there was a whole paradigm of words like **thence,** and therein lies the problem with such non-transparent terms, however elegant they are: they usually come in pairs, and it's hard to remember which is which. What's more, they often sound similar.

Not many people will mix up **horizontal** and **vertical** because at least one of these terms is completely transparent. We all know which way the horizon goes.

Then there's something like **starboard** and **port,** which is actually *more* transparent than **left/right,** but only for seafarers. The rest of us struggle to remember them correctly, but at least they sound very different, giving our memory something to latch on to.

And then there's the nightmare-difficulty level, neither transparent nor dissimilar: **convex** and **concave,** or **longitude** and **latitude.** And this is where I think pairs like **thence** and **thither** belong. So I'd guess eventually people just gave up.

Comment: are you suggesting there was _always_ a problem with these words for at lot of people?  i suppose the old _from whence_ bears witness to a tendency to reaffirm something non-obvious

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on the others' comments about paradigms: although misfortune can befall individual words, you do have to look at the whole system.

With "thence" we lost "whence" and the non-figurative sense of "hence" ("Get thee hence"). We lost "henceforth" and "thenceforth". We lost "thither", "whither", and "hither". We lost "wherefore" and "therefore" became elevated. "Hereafter" and "thereafter" were relegated to fixed meanings and poetic diction. "Wherein", "therein", "herein" went the way of "whereupon", "thereupon", "hereupon".

In short, our prepositions became more atomic. This is arguably a minor typological shift from synthetic to analytic. Individual pieces combine to yield the meaning. Less concise, but less space in memory.

Broaden your search further and you find verbal endings being neutralized in favour of explicit subjects, separate from the verb. A future tense grows out of the repurposed particle "will". Particles abound.